# Countdown Timer That Begins From a Timestamp

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, countdowntimer

I'm trying to link a countdown timer in Dart with my Firebase database, the countdown **starts** (timestamp) when the post is published and **ends** 10 seconds later.

My Dart code works, when I post to the database, my countdown is linked to the post, and the post is removed from the database **onEnd**, however, the timer is not linked to the post, and every refresh of the page restarts.

This code illustrates the *working* conditions described in the previous paragraph.

```
TweenAnimationBuilder<Duration>(
                    duration: Duration(seconds: 10),
                    tween: Tween(begin: Duration(seconds: 10), end: Duration.zero),
                    onEnd: () {
                      deletePost(
                          widget.snap['postId']
                              .toString(),
                      );
```

I want **Begin** to be the post (timestamp) in the Firebase database, so I tried something like this. 'datePublished' is the time the post was created in Firebase.

```
TweenAnimationBuilder<Duration>(
                        duration: Duration(seconds: 10),
                        tween: Tween(begin: widget.snap['datePublished'], end: Duration.zero),
                        onEnd: () {
                          deletePost(
                              widget.snap['postId']
                                  .toString(),
                          );
```

and it returns

> Expected a value of type 'Duration?', but got one of type 'Timestamp'

Firebase does not have a type 'Duration' from what I see so is there another way to do this?

***Update***

Per some suggestions and as a way to create a link to the back-end (Firebase) I created a Firestore method 'timer' with a integer value of secondsPerMinute and passed it like this:

```
TweenAnimationBuilder<Duration>(
                   duration: Duration(seconds: widget.snap['timer']),
                   tween: Tween(begin: Duration(seconds: 10), end: Duration.zero),
                   onEnd: () {
                     deletePost(
                         widget.snap['postId']
                             .toString(),
                     );
```

This creates a correct output in relation to the back-end however, the front-end and back-end are still not "attached" so to speak (every time the page is refreshed the countdown starts over from 10 seconds) my goal is to create a permanent relationship between the creation of the post and the post being deleted after 10 seconds no matter if the user navigates away from the page or closes the page/application all together.

Comment: You can substract the timestamp forn Date.now(). it will result Duration. Could you try?

Comment: It might be best to have the `Timer` run elsewhere in your application, so that it is not affected by the user navigating away from the page. If you are using any State Management solution, the main `state` would be the ideal place to run the `Timer`.

Comment: check runTimeType of `widget.snap['datePublished']`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh the Type is 'DateTime', I also realize now I actually want the "begin" time to be "datePublished plus 10 seconds" which is does do when using 'duration' however it doesn't stay relative to the post IE: if I refresh the page at 5 seconds it goes back to 10 seconds on the countdown, also if I add a post and it gets down to say 5 seconds and I add another post, they both start at 10 seconds instead of the first post being at 5 seconds.

Comment: you must cast widget.snap['datePublished'] to duration

Comment: @anggadaz If I do that like this ` TweenAnimationBuilder<Duration>(
                   duration:  widget.snap['datePublished'],
                   tween: Tween(begin: Duration(seconds: 10), end: Duration.zero),` I get "Expected a value of type 'Duration', but got one of type 'Timestamp'"

Answer (score 0):

Firebase has no futures, like deleting documents after some period of time. But there is, always, a way you can achieve it.

1. The best way is to run a server with will track end delete documents that need to be deleted.
2. You can delete documents using user computer to trigger this event. To do that create a document with, for example, `datePublished` field using firebase `serverTimestamp()` because of this timestamp will appear when document will be saved in Firestore you need to right before document was saved download it takes that timestamp and create a new timestamp by adding offset to it and save in another field for example `expirationDate` when document meant to be deleted. Init a countdown function with will delete document. To avoid that, countdown will be turned off by exiting application or by refreshing application create event that will always trigger on refreshes or opening application and only when user is a creator of a document to trigger countdown again.
3. Do everything like in 2. example, but don't trigger any countdowns. If user can't read data, data for him not exist. Every time, make requests with query that won't get documents out of date and secure database using rules if it's necessary that user can't get this data. Once a while like for example once a week trigger a firebase function with will delete all out of date documents and that's it.

The second solution is bad in my opinion. It will trigger many failed queries.